# JS - how to get content of internal style element (<style>...</style)

Tags: javascript, css

by internal style I mean

```
<style>
#div
{color:red;}
</style>
```

document.getElementsByTagName('style').innerHTML is not working... document.styleSheets either.

Comment: is this like <div class="somethig>any internal element</div> ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**`document.getElementsByTagName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns Array of Elements

so you need to access it with `index`

```
document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].innerHTML
```

[**`document.styleSheets`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets) is much useful  if you want to get specific selector or modify something from style sheet

Example

```
var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[1]; 
// assuming second one is embedded style, 
// since document.styleSheets also shows linked style sheets (like <link heref=".. >)

for (var i = 0; i < styleSheet.rules.length; i++) {
    // if you are looking for selector '.main'
    if (styleSheet.rules[i].selectorText === '.main') {
        // get background color
        var oldBg = styleSheet.rules[i].style.backgroundColor;

        // set background color
        styleSheet.rules[i].style.backgroundColor = '#ddd';
    }    
}
```

Comment: And document.styleSheets is an array, access it with index too : document.styleSheets[0].innerHTML

Comment: @karkael `document.styleSheets` returns `object` not `array` but we can still access it with `[0]` since the object keys are 0, 1, 2.., but there is no `innerHTML` to access. its a `CSSStyleSheet` type object

Answer (score 2):

`document.styleSheets` is an array , for each of the style definition in your page .
Iterate for each of the style elements and find the rules defined.

```
document.styleSheets[0].rules
```

This is again an array. so iterate . The rule text for each of the rules can be extracted as follows

```
document.styleSheets[indexofstyleelement].rules[indexofrule].cssText
```

`document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].cssText` gives rule text for first of the rules defined inside first style element

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #div {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("STYLE")[1];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.innerHTML;
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mediaguru/xt9mkncx/

Answer (score 0):

using jquery use this

```
var x = $('style').html();
```

using javascript

```
var x=document.getElementById("home");
```

`var y = x.firstChild.innerHTML;`

Comment: Please don't post jQuery answers to a non-jQuery question.

Comment: He did give JS answer too, so it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I'm so stupid..

```
for (var i = 0; i < styles_length; i++)
{// I had:
// styles.innerHTML;
// not correct:
styles[i].innerHTML;
}
```

All answers by @Jag, @ABHIJITH GM, @mediaguru, @hardik are correct.

Thank you guys! And sorry for this newbie question... all day codding, my eyes are hurting, coffee time.